# Exception in Flink Streaming to Kafka Avro Sink java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro, flink-streaming

I'm Using flink streaming to read events from Kafka source topic and after de-duplication, writing to separate kafka topic in avro topic.
Flow

> Kafka Topic(json format) -> flink streaming(de-duplication) -> scala
> case class objects -> Kafka Topic(Avro Format)

```
    val sink = sinkProvider.getKafkaSink(brokerURL, targetTopic,kafkaTransactionMaxTimeoutMs, kafkaTransactionTimeoutMs)
    messageStream
      .map {
        record =>
          convertJsonToExample(record)
      }
      .sinkTo(sink)
      .name("Example Kafka Avro Sink")
      .uid("Example-Kafka-Avro-Sink")
```

Here are the steps I followed:

1. I created avro schema for my output schema

```
    {
   "type":"record",
   "name":"Example",
   "namespace":"ca.ix.dcn.test",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"x",
         "type":"string"
      },
      {
         "name":"y",
         "type":"long"
      }
   ]
}
```

2. From avro schema I generated case class using avro-hugger tools(version 1.2.1) for
   SpecificRecord
3. I used flink AvroSerializationSchema forSpecificRecord cause flink
   kafka avro sink let's you use either specific record or generic
   record constructor for serialization to avro.

```
  def getKafkaSink(brokers: String, targetTopic: String,transactionMaxTimeoutMs:String,transactionTimeoutMs:String) = {

    val schema = ReflectData.get.getSchema(classOf[Example])
    val sink = KafkaSink.builder()
      .setBootstrapServers(brokers)
      .setProperty("transaction.max.timeout.ms",transactionMaxTimeoutMs)
      .setProperty("transaction.timeout.ms",transactionTimeoutMs)
      .setRecordSerializer(KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder()
        .setTopic(targetTopic)
        .setValueSerializationSchema(AvroSerializationSchema.forSpecific[Example](classOf[Example]))

        .setPartitioner(new FlinkFixedPartitioner())
        .build()
      )
      .setDeliveryGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.EXACTLY_ONCE)
      .build()
    sink
  }
```

Now when I run it I get the exeption:

```
  Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData can not access a member of class ca.ix.dcn.test with modifiers "private final"
  at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.createSchema(SpecificData.java:405)
  at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectData.createSchema(ReflectData.java:734)
```

I saw there is a bug opened on flink for this:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-18478
But I didn't find any work around for this.

Wondering if there is any workaround for this. Also if there are detailed examples that explain how to use flink streaming sink(for avro) using AvroSerializationSchema(Specific/Generic)

Appreciate the help on this.

Answer (score 1):

In the Flink ticket that you're linking to, there's a comment made that avro-hugger is not really compatible with the Apache Avro Java library, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-18478?focusedCommentId=17164456&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-17164456

The solution would be to generate Avro Java POJOs and use them in your Scala application.

Comment: thanks @martijn. I ended up using POJO. Although I generated it from sbt-avro.